# Why does ExtJS subtract a day when formatting a date?

Tags: date, extjs4

Using `ExtJS 4.0.2`, I can type the following into the console:

```
Ext.util.Format.date('2012-01-13', "m-d-Y");
```

I get `01-12-2012`

Why?
I can correct it with:

```
Ext.util.Format.date('2012-01-13 00:00:00', "m-d-Y");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext.util.Format.date in Ext 4.0.2 uses a Date object or a String (your case). This string is parsed using the native Date.parse() using the UTC time zone.

Try to explicitly parse it using Ext.Date.parse:

```
var dt = Ext.Date.parse("2012-01-13", "Y-m-d");
Ext.util.Format.date(dt, "m-d-Y");
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem exists in Ext3, but the solution is slightly different:

```
var dt = '2012-01-31'; //date string
dt = Date.parseDate(dt, "Y-m-d");
Ext.util.Format.date(dt, 'm/d/Y'); //returns 01/31/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to use Gregor's answer (e.g. filling a grid), note that changing the input to a non ISO 8601 date format will avoid the UTC parsing as well. For example

```
Ext.util.Format.date('01/13/2012', "Y-m-d");
```

will give `2012-01-13`