# Custom Renderer in Ext-js - Bryntum/ExtJs UTC Date Issue

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, utc, renderer

I'm trying to add a **custom renderer** to Bryntum Ext Gantt chart.

I have dates which are being shown in the local timezone, but I wish to show them in the UTC date because this is what the datasource is using to present the user with date (it's agnostic of browser time-zone) in the source application.

The post here led me in the right direction (seems to be what I need based on my tests): [Why does ExtJS subtract a day when formatting a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023641/why-does-extjs-subtract-a-day-when-formatting-a-date)

*How do I implement linked solution into a custom renderer*?

---

I tried this and the column was blank:

```
{
    xtype:'startdatecolumn',
    sortable: false,
    text: 'Start',
    dataIndex: 'StartDate',
    renderer: function (v, m, r) {
        return Ext.util.Format.date(Ext.Date.parse(v, "Y-m-d"), "m-d-Y");
    }
}
```

Also tried this and the column was blank:

```
{
    xtype:'startdatecolumn',
    sortable: false,
    text: 'Start',
    dataIndex: 'StartDate',
    renderer: function (v) {
        var dt = Ext.Date.parse(v, "Y-m-d");
        Ext.util.Format.date(dt, "m-d-Y");
        return dt;
    }
}
```

With this format, it shows the date in local timezone (incorrect unless set to UTC).

```
{   
    xtype:'enddatecolumn',
    dataIndex: 'EndDate',
    sortable: false,
    text: 'End'
}
```

---

## Bryntum Column Example

```
 columns : [
            {
                xtype : 'treecolumn',
                header: 'Tasks',
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'Name',
                width: 200,
                field: {
                    allowBlank: false
                },
                renderer : function(v, meta, r) {
                    if (!r.data.leaf) meta.tdCls = 'sch-gantt-parent-cell';

                    return v;
                }
            },
            {
                xtype : 'startdatecolumn'
            },
            {
                //hidden : true,
                xtype : 'enddatecolumn'
            },
```

Comment: Are you using `console.log()` blocks to observe what the data is as it's being seen by the renderer handler? `console.log(v);` would be a start, for instance. Or I suppose use breakpoints in the console Javascript tabs.

Comment: Yes, I do use console.log(), but definitely could spend some time learning the firebug / chrome consoles better. Any recommended resources besides just trial and error?

Comment: As ExtJS is your particular situation here, I'll defer to [Sencha's support docs](http://www.sencha.com/learn/debugging-ext-js-applications/), which does give some good tips and seems to be big Firebug fans (as I am, since it came out in beta). See the bottom of the article for a list of screencasts and tutorials on Firebug. Having said that, though, Chrome Console is pretty good, and some people really like Venkman and Fiddler too. IE "developer tools" are a waste of time IMO.

Comment: Thanks for that; I must have skipped over that section :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed using this function:

```
function niceDate (v, m, r) {
            var dt =    padStr(1 + v.getMonth()) + 
                        '-' +
                        padStr(v.getDate()) +
                        '-' +
                        padStr(v.getFullYear());
            return dt;
           }

function padStr(i) {
    return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : "" + i;
}
```

and in the column renderer :

```
                   {
                    xtype:'startdatecolumn',
                    sortable: false,
                    text: 'Start',
                    dataIndex: 'StartDate',
                    renderer: niceDate
                    }
```

When parsing the xml, I use a switch function with the following for timestamps:

```
case 'timestamp':
    if(!empty(v))
    v = new Date(parseInt(v));
    break;
```

This seems to reliably feed a "date" object to ext.js and the column is rendered to match our sources date formatting using the renderer.

Comment: Thanks for your work! Did you allow editing of your start/stop dates? I'm seeing similar issues with the DatePicker: the editor renders the  date - 1 (StartDate as UTC with browser's timezone applied).